# Parsing string results in duplicated values

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I have a string that contains an arbitrary amount of integers with an arbitrary amount of digits, and I need to parse each integer into an element of a matrix the program previously allocated. For some reason the output is duplicating the last digits of the string when a new string is given, like so:

data.txt

```
1 4 5 6 8
5 5 5 5 5
3 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 1
```

program output:

```
1 4 5 6 5
5 5 5 5 3
3 3 3 3 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

I can see that the last element of each row is being overwritten by the first element of the next row, but I have no idea WHY it is doing this. Here's the relevant code:

```
    while(getline(inFile, readIn)) {
        parse(readIn, mtrx, r);
        r++;
    }

//......

void parse(string str, matrix& mtrx, int r)
{
    string value = "";
    str.append("*");
    int i=0;                        //finds integers in string
    int c=0;                        //place holders for columns
    while( i < str.length() ) {
        value = "";
        while( str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '*' ) {
            value += str[i];
            i++;
        }
        mtrx.set(r,c, atoi(value.c_str()));
        c++;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`). Learn how to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`). For arbitrarily large numbers, consider using a [bignum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum) library like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: Some tips: Use a vectors of vectors, read about [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter). Using that, it's actually very trivial to do this.

Comment: Why are you adding a '*' when you know what the length is?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your mtrx is just 4x4 elements, because in C++ there is no array bounds testing by default, so you can read beyond the bounds. When writing the last element of a row, you write the first element of the next row, which is overwritten when you write the next row. When reading the last element of a row, you read the first element of the next row. The last element in the last row is ok, because you wrote beyond the array itself and read this back, but this can cause some interesting other problems.